# Signal patterns between train and test sets are vastly inconsistent

Tags: signal-analysis, machine-learning, deep-learning

I am trying to build a machine learning classification model of a given signal dataset of 3 classes (one file for train signal data is another one for test data). I tried different machine learning methods and almost all of them perform very poorly on the unseen testing data. I was surprised that the loss gets close to zero while the val_loss is very high (clearly my model overfits so badly).

```
3/3 [==============================] - 0s 19ms/step - loss: 0.0676 - val_loss: 2.8459
```

I did my investigation and tried to see if there is something wrong with the data. I plot the signals from each class in both train and test. I found the following HUGE differences in signal patterns. For instance, see how much difference between the class 1 in train data vs. class 1 in test data.

[image]

[image]

I thought there was some mistake during the labeling phase so I tried to map all classes from the train and test sets to see for instance if class 1 from the train set matches class 2 from the test set, but surprisingly no mapping exists at all, meaning that there was something wrong during the data collection or possibly the data is corrupted.

Do you think the aforementioned analysis is sensible? Any extra thoughts and hints on how to overcome this issue is highly appreciated.

Comment: Your analysis seems very sensible. Nothing much you can do with bad data.

Comment: Have you done feature analysis? We don't know what you're after hence we can not say that if they look differently they are actually different. Do you use Deep Learning?

Comment: @Royi Yes, I have. I exhausted all possible solutions before asking here. And yes I use LSTM here. I spent one month in this problem :(

Comment: Could you share more information on the data and what you see? There is always a chance for a wrong labeling but could it be features are not well extracted?